# How images are mapped in Contao news Extension?

Tags: contao

I am doing a newsmigration to latest Contao 4.

```
Can anyone please explain how the image files are related to tl_news table ?
Currently for my migration I have imagepath and imagename for the respective image.

When I add an image to a news in contao through backend. The following fields get updated in database.
```

addImage => 1,

singleSRC => f52a3871946211e782662e3e7a222c66

```
But when I search singleSRC in tl_files.uuid , it doesn't show any records.
```

Please help me to find how the images can be mapped during migration  to Contao 4

Answer (score 2):

The `singleSRC` field in `tl_news` (and also `tl_content` and `tl_calendar_events` for example) is a **binary** field containing an UUID that relates to the `tl_files.uuid` field.

I do not know how exactly you implemented your news migration script. But within the Contao framework, this is how you get the path to a file from `singleSRC` for example:

```php
// $objNews is a \Contao\NewsModel object
$objFile = \Contao\FilesModel::findByUuid($objNews->singleSRC);
$strPath = $objFile->path;
```

And this is how you would add it back to the new news entry somewhere else:

```php
// $strPath contains the relative path of the file on the other installation
$objFile = \Contao\Dbafs::addResource($strPath);
$objNews->singleSRC = $objFile->uuid;
```